# How can I handle an exception in C#?

Tags: c#, exception

I'm trying to handle an exception to avoid my program crash if `double.Parse(string)` tries parsing invalid values (such as strings instead of numbers). Here's what I've got:

```
do
{
    //asking customer the amount of shirts he would like to buy any shirts they want.
    numbershirtString = Console.ReadLine(); // customer types in amount of shirts they want.
    numbershirts = double.Parse(numbershirtString);

    keepLooping = true;

    if (numbershirts < 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You would be buying " + numbershirts + " shirts");
        keepLooping = false;
    }

    if (numbershirts > 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You cannot order more than 10 shirts. Please try again.");
        keepLooping = true;
    }

} while (keepLooping);
```

I would appreciate your help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: C# 7.0 `if (double.TryParse(s, out var i)) { use i } else { do something without i}`

Answer (score 1):

Use `double.TryParse()` instead. It returns `true` of `false` depending on the outcome:

```
double val;
bool success = double.TryParse("red", out val);
if(success)
{
    // val contains a parsed value
}
else
{
    // could not parse
}
```

Comment: The return value depends on the input ;o)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a little advanced for you, but if you are feeling in a clever mood, you can define a class that handles the parsing of user input. That way you can keep that logic separated from your main program (see [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)).

```
public class UserEntry
{
    private readonly string _originalValue;

    public UserEntry(string input)
    {
        _originalValue = input;
    }

    public bool IsInt
    {
        get
        {
            return int.TryParse(_originalValue, out var dummy);
        }           
    }

    public int ToInt()
    {
        return ToInt(default(int));
    }

    public int ToInt(int defaultValue)
    {
        int result;

        bool ok = int.TryParse(_originalValue, out result);
        return ok ? result : defaultValue;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _originalValue;
    }

    static public implicit operator UserEntry(string input)
    {
        return new UserEntry(input);
    }

    static public implicit operator Int32(UserEntry input)
    {
        return input.ToInt();
    }
}
```

If we use implicit conversion operators it makes things very simple. For example, all of these are now legal:

```
UserEntry entry = Console.ReadLine();
if (!entry.IsInt) continue;
if (entry < 10) return entry;
```

If we apply this to your example, it shortens your code a bit, and arguably makes it a bit clearer as well.

```
public class Program
{
    private const int MaximumOrder = 10;

    public static void Main()
    {
        var n = AskForNumberOfShirts();
        Console.WriteLine("OK, I'll order {0} shirts.", n);
    }

    public static int AskForNumberOfShirts()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of shirts to order:");
            UserEntry entry = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!entry.IsInt)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You entered an invalid number.");
                continue;
            }
            if (entry > MaximumOrder)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is too many! Please enter {1} or fewer.", entry, MaximumOrder);
                continue;
            }
            return entry;
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. I doubt you can order half a shirt, so I am using an `int` instead of a `double` to store the number of shirts.
2. I refactored the logic branches to use opportunistic return, a.ka. Guard Pattern. [See this article for why I do this](https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/).
3. I extracted the constant value `10` to its own symbol, `MaximumOrder`. This should get you a couple points on the assignment.

Output:

```
Enter the number of shirts to order:
22
22 is too many! Please enter 10 or fewer.
Enter the number of shirts to order:
sdlfkj
You entered an invalid number.
Enter the number of shirts to order:
9
OK, I'll order 9 shirts.
```

[Working example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5mbZQn)

Answer (score 0):

To handle an exception, in C# like similar in other languages, you can use the `try..catch` block.
Look at the simplest syntax:

```
try
{
    //Try to run some code.
}
catch
{
    //Do something if anything excepted.
}
```

If you're interested to retrieve which exception breaked the code:

```
try
{
    //Try to run some code.
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Do something ex was thrown.
}
```

If you change the type of `ex` to something inheriting the base class `Exception` you'll handle only all the exception of that type:

```
try
{
    //Try to run some code.
}
catch (StackOverflowException ex)
{
    //Do something ex was thrown because you overflowed the stack.
}
```

But instead of talking about `try..catch` block which you can find out more about on Google, I suggest you to use the method `double.TryParse(string, out double)`.
Its syntax is a little bit different than `double.Parse`, but effectively it does the same in a different way.
It returns `true` if your input is valid, else it returns `false`, whereas in the first parameter you have just to pass your `string` input and in the second one is required an output reference to the result variable:

```
double x = 0;
string number = "125.3";
if (double.TryParse(number, out x))
    Console.WriteLine("Your number is " + x.ToString());
else
    Console.WriteLine("Your input isn't valid");
```